# How can you set a limit to S3 bucket size in AEM 6.2

Tags: amazon-s3, aem

Is there a configuration to set the limit on S3 bucket size in AEM 6.2. I am aware of S3 cache size that can be configured using the S3 data store configuration file.

My issue is that S3 bucket can grow exponentially and although there is no limit to the size but there is a constraint on budget. For example if my bucket size in 250GB and it more or less stays the same after every compaction. I don't ever want it to cross 1TB.

I am aware that S3 can limit this but I want to do it via AEM so that operations don't fail and data store is never corrupted.

Any hints?

Comment: What do you expect AEM to do when the limit is reached?

Comment: *"I am aware that S3 can limit this."* Are you sure about that?  Buckets have no size limit.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I was referring to alerts rather than configurable limits but yes point taken that my statement is a bit misleading. Thanks for pointing out. As others have clarified there are no known settings for this behaviour in AEM.

Comment: It's unlikely that your S3 bucket will grow exponentially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no configuration available that will limit the size of Amazon S3 buckets.

You can, however, obtain [Amazon S3 metrics in Amazon CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). You could **create an alarm on a bucket to send a notification** when the amount of data stored in an Amazon S3 bucket exceeds a certain threshold.